# jQuery.click <a href="#">

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to add a click event to an `a` element with a `href` of `#` e.g.
`<a href="#">Blah!</a>`

```
    jQuery('a').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked!');
    });
```

This works for every `a` except those with `href="#"`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Not working in any browser in Windows.

```js
jQuery('a').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Blah!</a>
```

Comment: You forgot to accept an `event` parameter for the handler. Even for environments that have the global `event`, see snippet, cannot reproduce.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by `Even for environments that have the global event`? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't depend on `event` being globally defined. Use it as a parameter for the handler instead.

Comment: Can you add in which environment/browser this *doesn't* work for you?

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like this:

```
jQuery('a').click(function(e)  { 
   if($(this).attr("href") == "#"){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("clicked");
   }
});
```

Or use something like this:

```
jQuery('a[href$="#"]').click(function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();     
   console.log("clicked"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @CertainPerformance said, you forgot to pass the event handler as a parameter to your function.Just change your code from

```
jQuery('a').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicked!');
});
```

to

```
jQuery('a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicked!');
});
```